# Html in label choice form

Tags: forms, symfony, twig, html-escape-characters

In `choiceType` field I have parameter - choice label

```
   'choice_label' => function ($pay, $key, $index) {
        return "<b>".$pay->getName()."</b><br />";
    },
```

And render function of fields in twig:

```
{{form_widget(field)}}
{{form_errors(field)}}
```

Of course I want to render `getName` in bold characters, 
I have try with twig `autoescape` and `{{form_widget(field)|raw}}` - without success

Comment: Try `return new \Twig_Markup("<b>".$pay->getName()."</b><br />", "UTF-8");`

Comment: @DarkBee does not work

Comment: AFAIK html tag for `<option>` content is not support by browsers. Try with css styles.

Comment: It is not `<option>` I rendered choiceType as radio button, so `choice_label` is in `<label>`

Answer (score 2):

You have to custom the choice_label form in a custom theme (ex : radioHTML.html.twig) => I just add |raw to the label text

```
{%- block form_label -%}
{% if label is not same as(false) -%}
    {% if not compound -%}
        {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'for': id}) %}
    {%- endif -%}
    {% if required -%}
        {% set label_attr = label_attr|merge({'class': (label_attr.class|default('') ~ ' required')|trim}) %}
    {%- endif -%}
    {% if label is empty -%}
        {%- if label_format is not empty -%}
            {% set label = label_format|replace({
                '%name%': name,
                '%id%': id,
            }) %}
        {%- else -%}
            {% set label = name|humanize %}
        {%- endif -%}
    {%- endif -%}
    <{{ element|default('label') }}{% if label_attr %}{% with { attr: label_attr } %}{{ block('attributes') }}{% endwith %}{% endif %}>
    {%- if translation_domain is same as(false) -%}
        {{- label|raw -}}
    {%- else -%}
        {{- label|trans({}, translation_domain)|raw -}}
    {%- endif -%}
    </{{ element|default('label') }}>
{%- endif -%}
{%- endblock form_label -%}
```

Your form type just return html string in the choice_label option :

```
 $builder->add('fieldName', EntityType::class, array(
            'required' => true,
            'class' => 'AppBundle\EntityName',
            'choice_label' => function (EntityName $entity) {
                $html = '<div>';
                $html .= $entity->getName();
                $html .= '</div>';
                return $html;
            },
            'data' => null,
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded' => true)
```

And then use it for your specific field like that in your twig TPL :

```
{% form_theme from.fieldNalme 'form/radioHTML.html.twig' %}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since Symfony 5.1 `'label_html' => true` can be set to allow HTML in labels.

Note that this does not work with `'expanded' => false`, as this renders a HTML select box (which per its nature does not support HTML in the value label).

```php
$builder->add('mychoices', ChoiceType::class, [
    'required' => true,
    'expanded' => true,
    'choices' => ['Test 1', 'Test 2'],
    'label_html' => true,
    'choice_label' => function ($label) {
        return '<strong>' . $label . '</strong>';
    },
]);
```

Comment: It seems it doesn't work on choice labels.

Comment: `choice_label` works for me. I adapted my use case and added an example above?
I'm using radio buttons here. Not sure if that makes a difference with checkboxes.

Comment: I think I understood. It works with radios, but not with a select (expanded → false).  @see https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/40806